# Showing products price if logged in or for a specific product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have some code that is blocking the price from being shown on all products, if the user is not logged in.

My issue is that I have 1 product that is free, and I need the price to be shown, if the user is not logged in.

Can someone help me target that single product by his id and show this particular price even if the user is not logged in.

Here is my original php code in **`funcions.php`** which blocks the price from being shown, when a user is not logged in:

```
// Hide prices on public woocommerce (not logged in)
add_action('after_setup_theme','activate_filter') ; 
function activate_filter(){
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'show_price_logged');
}
function show_price_logged($price){
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        return $price;
    }
    else
    {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    return '<a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">Call for pricing</a>';
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have always the fixed product id which you want to show the price for?

Comment: yes, I could use the product ID.

Comment: reposted in wordpress dev. repo... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255438/have-woocommerce-show-product-price-if-id-when-not-logged-in

Comment: Not worth reposting. This is WooCommerce-specific and will probably get closed at the WordPress stack.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up a bit and abstracted your conditional test to a custom function called `so_42075748_hide_price()` which tests if the user is logged in *and* tests if the product's price is greater than zero. I've also filtered `woocommerce_is_purchasable` to make these products completely not purchasable to someone who may know that you can simply do `?add-to-cart=99` to add a product to the cart.

```
// Switch the Price HTML
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'so_42075748_hide_price_logged', 10, 2 );
function so_42075748_hide_price_logged( $price, $product ){
    if( so_42075748_hide_price( $product ) ){
        // Not the ideal permalink in my opinion, but copying from original question.
        $price = '<a href="' . get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Call for pricing', 'your-textdomain' ) . '</a>';
    }
    return $price;
}

// Make products completely unpurchasable
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'so_42075748_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
function so_42075748_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){ 
    if( so_42075748_hide_price( $product ) ){
        $purchasable = false;
    }
    return $purchasable;
}

// Hide add to cart buttons
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'so_42075748_hide_prices' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'so_42075748_hide_prices' );
function so_42075748_hide_prices(){
    global $product; 

    if( so_42075748_hide_price( $product ) ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```

**Edited:** Made a more complete conditional test that also tests if the price is null.

```
// Your condition for hiding products
function so_42075748_hide_price( $product = null ){

    if( ! is_object( $product ) ){
        return true;
    }

    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){

        $price = $product->get_price();

        if( ! is_null( $price ) && $price > 0 ){
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to have worked, however when I checked a product with variations, it seems to show the options but acts as if the item is out of stock... vs. hiding the add to cart button all together..

Comment: actually variable products actually show the price.. is that due to the fact that there is not a price set? because it is variable..

Comment: I didn't really consider variable products too much in my answer, but the variable product's price is determined from it's variations. What prices do you have for the variations? And can you `var_dump($product->get_price())` somewhere in the `so_42075748_hide_prices()` function? and let me know what that says.

Comment: I have many prices for the variation, depends on the product....

not sure what to do with the var_dump

Comment: Thanks Helga, I am not sure what to do with the var dump, although I do have a working solution now, it does not use the purchasable filter... which I did like how you suggested the use of that filter... however in this case the order would simply not be fullfilled if they were to add that string to the url

Comment: Looks like I left out a word. I was hoping you could *add* the `var_dump` into the function so we could see what the `get_price()` is returning for a variable product.

Comment: I've updated my conditional and tested it a few more times. Please give it a try.  Important to note, that if none of the variations have prices, then the options will display and the item will say that it is unavailable, which happened to me at first. That's a different can of worms though.